# Giving a rights to the webpart

Tags: development

How Can I give a rights to the webpart. Now only I can see projecting by me webpart. I getting this error when I try to open each of user without me:

[image]

How Can I set a User privilages to the grup. At user privilages I have got this: And I'm in main group:

[image]

How Can I setup a rights to webpart.

Comment: Is this a custom web part? If so, the users will need rights to whatever you are accessing inside the webpart. If they don't, then you will get the access denied page that you are seeing.

Comment: This is a Visual web Part. Please tell me how add all privilages to webpart to all uisers see it. I have got 5 lists meybe one of them havent got a privilages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember when creating custom web parts to make sure code, which gets data from lists that require login to see, is placed within a [`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) block.

Answer (score 0):

I manage with it by coment Throttling function:

```
// lstOtherList.EnableThrottling = false;
```